# Ripple effect BoxShadow not showing?

Tags: html, css

I'm using Fian's [Waves](http://fian.my.id/Waves) for the ripple effect. The problem is when I include a `box-shadow` property to a button with the 'waves-circle' class, it doesn't show any shadow.

**CODE**

```
<style>
.button {
  background-color: Turquoise;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);

  outline: 0;
}
</style>

<button class="button waves">0</button>

<script>
Waves.attach('.waves', ['waves-circle']);
Waves.init();
</script>
```

Now if I add the 'waves-float' to the 'script', it does appear the shadow but the effect is overflowing outside it's border. What I want is to fit the effect exactly onto the button's border with the `box-shadow` property.

```
Waves.attach('.waves', ['waves-circle', 'waves-float']);
```

Any idea what I'm missin'?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
class="waves-effect"
```

`.waves-effect` has `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: thanks for the answer. i tried it but still the same. the effect isn't filling the entire circle...